# How to redirect stdout output to a new Vim tab?

Tags: vim

I'm editing an XML file in Vim, and then I want to transform it a plain-text file with xsltproc, which by default outputs to a stdout (something like : !xsltproc TXTRULE.XSL %). Is it possible to redirect that xsltproc output to a new tab in Vim without creating any intermediate files?

(I've tried to read :help redir and [some wiki notes](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Capture_ex_command_output), but still can't get it. would be greateful for some kind of simple example.)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use [read](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#:read!) like in the following:

```
:read !ls
```

Obviously you should change `ls` with your command. If you want to open a new tab prepend [tabnew](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/tabpage.html#:tabnew) with a bar to the command like:

```
:tabnew|read !ls
```

Answer (score 4):

To expand on lucapette's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8287358/85615), you could create a map like this:

```
:map ,x :tabnew<Bar>read !xsltproc TXTRULE.XSL #
```

`#` expands to the previously opened buffer, which is the file you were editing, while `%` would expand to the new buffer opened by `:tabnew`.

`<Bar>` has to be used instead of `|`, because otherwise, the `:map` command would end at the `|`.

Comment: Thanks **Daniel**, i didn't know about #. However, from my side, I may add that it seems one may use `\|` instead of `<Bar>` :).

Comment: Cool answer I tend to forget about `#`

Comment: You have two problems here: 1) [Never use `:map`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html) (additionally, you don’t need this mapping in operator-pending mode, so either `nnoremap` or `nnoremap`+`xnoremap`) 2) `#` should not be ever used as well as it is impossible to properly handle special (special for shell) characters this way, `:execute` and `shellescape(@#, 1)` are your friends here. And did not you forget `<CR>` at the end?

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following to view my program outputs (very useful for a makefile with a make run rule)

It opens a new tab next to current one only if one was not already opened before for that purpose:

```
fu! RedirStdoutNewTabSingle(cmd)
  let a:newt= expand('%:p') . ".out.tmp"
  tabnext
  if expand('%:p') != a:newt
    tabprevious
    exec "tabnew" . a:newt
  else
    exec "%d"
  endif
  exec 'silent r !' . a:cmd
  set nomodified
endfunc

au FileType xml noremap <buffer> <F6> :call RedirStdoutNewTabSingle("xsltproc")<CR>
```